Use query criteria to filter storeName column
I have a form f_Responses with a combobox cboCustomers for getting customer responses. There are two append queries "q_ClearCustomer" and "q_AppendCustomer" behind the On Click event of btn_GetStore.
Table t_Customer has 50,000 records with 4 columns
|StoreName | Platform | FName    | LastName |
| Cus001   | rainbows | Richards | JohnsonR |
| Cus002   | Takestwo | Sameons  | SamsondS |
| Col001   | Takestwo | AlleniX  | JonneteA |
| Cus001   | rainbows | Raymonds | JohnsonR |
| Cus002   | Takestwo | Sameons  | SamsondS |
| Cus001   | rainbows | Rowlands | JohnsonR |
| Cus002   | Takestwo | Solomon  | SamsondS |

When I need to process records identified as Cus002 I will select from cboCustomers in f_Responses which will populate txtCustomer. Then clicking btn_GetStore is suppose to populate f_Responses with Cus002 records.
I created an append query with cus002 in the criteria of StoreName. I also have the following StoreName = "Cus002" in f_Customer Property Sheet filter.
Do I have to go back to the append query change this criteria when I need to filter for Cus003 and others?
All assistance would be greatly appreciated.

You probably don't need any of the queries. Just apply a filter : DoCmd.ApplyFilter WhereCondition:="StoreName ='" & Me.cboCustomers & "'" or something like that.

Right, why duplicate records to another table when a filter can serve?

I think you need to create a form with a combobox populating all possible criteria so that users can simply select from there
Example see the where clause and see how we put the combo which reference your criteria on your append query
INSERT INTO tblWIPDebits ( BajID, PurchDate, BSIDReceipt, ReceiptInput, ReceipttAcc, Quanties, ProdCost, BSIDDebit, ReceiptsDebit, DebitAccount )
SELECT tblIssueSlip.SlipID, tblWIP.PurchDate, tblWIP.BSIDReceipt, tblWIP.ReceiptInput, tblWIP.ReceipttAcc, tblWIP.Quanties, tblWIP.ProdCost, "2" AS BSIDDebit, "Work in progress" AS ReceiptDebit, "114-10-1003" AS DebitAccount
FROM tblIssueSlip INNER JOIN tblWIP ON tblIssueSlip.SlipID = tblWIP.SlipID
WHERE (((tblIssueSlip.SlipID)=[Forms]![FrmIssuesPosting]![CboIssue]));

